# перекомпилируйте с параметром -fPIC

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Работаю над проектом(состоящий из нескольких подпроектов) Cmake с использование библиотеки wxWidgets, некоторые проекты не могут собраться по причине:

> /usr/local/lib/libwx_baseu-3.0.a(baselib_filename.o): перемещение R_X86_64_PC32 для символ «_ZN8wxString4nposE» не может использоваться при создании общий объект; перекомпилируйте с параметром -fPIC

Сборка на Windows происходит без проблем, проблемы только при сборке на Linux. И я не могу понять, мне нужно пересобирать wxWidgets библиотеку с параметром -fPIC или же мне нужно в CMakeList изменить тип сборки?

Если дело в wxWidgets, могу ли я обойти эту проблему без пересборки библиотеки?

Пробовал добавлять в CMakeList:`set(POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)` - не помогло.

Флаги сборки:`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-invalid-offsetof -std=c++0x -fpack-struct=1 ")`

Comment: Если вы почему-то самостоятельно собрали wx в динамические библиотеки без -fPIC, то нет, без их пересборки не обойтись. На Linux-архитектуре amd64 PIC в shared objects — обязательное условие. Если же вы работаете со статическими библиотеками (из текста ошибки вроде бы это следует), то убедитесь, что компилятор при сборке вашего проекта действительно запускается (то есть не используются ранее собранные файлы) и что он действительно запускается с -fPIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пересобрал библиотеки wxWidgets и собрал полностью проект

```
../configure --enable-shared CFLAGS=-fPIC CXXFLAGS=-fPIC
```

и добавил

```
set (CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)
```